# I answered my own question but it was deleted and I don't understand why

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-answers

[Extract badly formatted date from a mixed string and convert to YYYY-MM-DD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663284/extract-badly-formatted-date-from-a-mixed-string-and-convert-to-yyyy-mm-dd?noredirect=1#comment34524023_22663284)

I checked the FAQ but it just suggests that my answer did not fundamentally answer the question. The deletion confused other commenters as it meant context was lost.

Comment: Your answer sounded like an addition to your question; *I have included the code I use but I wonder if anyone can suggest any improvements.*

Comment: As such it was probably flagged as Not an Answer, and the moderator handling the flag didn't recognize it for an answer either.

Comment: I see. It was an answer, I am just open to the idea that it is not the best answer. I can't find any private message function. What should I do?

Comment: You can use the `flag` option, pick `other` and ask for an undelete, explaining your case. Do so after you updated your answer to make it clearer it is an answer (move the request for improvement suggestions to the end, at the very least).

Comment: @cassiopeia Answers aren't the best place to ask, "hey, can I do this better?" Makes it sound like it should be in the question, *especially* if you're the question owner and you have a low reputation.

Comment: OK I will bear that in mind. Thanks for your undelete.

Comment: Related: [How should we deal with an answer that answers the question, then follows up with another question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116951/how-should-we-deal-with-an-answer-that-answers-the-question-then-follows-up-wit)

Comment: Your question might fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Here is the edit that George made on your answer.  In the Moderator Dashboard, the moderator who deleted the answer would have only seen the text highlighted in red, unless he expanded the window.  At first glance, no additional investigation seems necessary, since the text clearly seems to indicate that a non-answer was posted.

[image]